# Safely moving and creating new tempdb files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, tempdb

Two things I'd like to know:

- how do you safely move tempdb with minimal downtime?
- how many tempdb files do you need?

Is it 1 file per core? So quad-core = 4 tempdb files, creating three new ones?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To move `tempdb` files, you simply need to do the following:

```
alter database tempdb
modify file
(
    name = tempdev,
    filename = 'C:\YourNewTempdbDir\tempdb.mdf'
)
go

alter database tempdb
modify file
(
    name = templog,
    filename = 'C:\YourNewTempdbDir\templog.ldf'
)
go
```

If you want to add a new file to `tempdb`, you simply need to do the following (provided you want to add it to the `PRIMARY` filegroup, or create your own):

```
alter database tempdb
add file
(
    name = tempdb2,
    filename = 'C:\YourNewTempdbDir\Tempdb2.ndf'
)
go
```

For these changes to take effect, you will need to restart the SQL Server service.  So **as far as minimizing downtime goes, you are constrained to the amount of time it will take for the service restart**.  You don't have to worry about moving the pre-existing `tempdb` database files, as SQL Server always recreates the files and the new locations/files will be created upon service startup.

As for the "1 tempdb data file per core", that is largely a myth.  The correct approach is to monitor `tempdb` file contention for the Page Free Space (PFS), Global Allocation Map (GAM), and the Shared Global Allocation Map (SGAM) pages.  Please reference [this article to get a query](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/breaking-down-tempdb-contention) [(alternative link)](http://sqlsoldier.net/wp/sqlserver/breakingdowntempdbcontention) that looks through the `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` DMV to see how much `tempdb` file contention there is.  Then you need to go off of this, instead of just blanketing `tempdb` with the same amount of files as there are cores.  It's the more advisable approach.

Answer (score 8):

1. To move tempdb, execute:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
   MODIFY FILE ( name=tempdev, filename='D:\Newpath\tempdb.mdf') 
   GO
   ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
   MODIFY FILE ( name=templog, filename='D:\Newpath\templog.ldf') 
   GO
   ```

   Then restart your SQL Server Service (MSSQLServer).
2. Number of files in tempdb - see Paul Randall's article: [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (12/30) tempdb should always have one data file per processor core](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-(1230)-tempdb-should-always-have-one-data-file-per-processor-core.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

From [Microsoft's advice](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2154845/recommendations-to-reduce-allocation-contention-in-sql-server-tempdb-d):

> As a general rule, if the number of logical processors is less than or equal to 8, use the same number of data files as logical processors.
>
> If the number of logical processors is greater than 8, use 8 data files and then if contention continues, increase the number of data files by multiples of 4 (up to the number of logical processors) until the contention is reduced to acceptable levels or make changes to the workload/code.

Moving the TempDB files is a 2-step process:

1. Tell SQL **where** you want your new TempDB files to go to (this doesn't have downtime)
2. **Restart** the `SQL Server` service for the change to take effect (this is the **minimum downtime** you need)

To tell SQL where to create the new TempDB files, you can use:

```
DECLARE @newDriveAndFolder VARCHAR(8000);

SET @newDriveAndFolder = 'Z:\YourTempDBfolder';

SELECT [name] AS [Logical Name]
    ,physical_name AS [Current Location]
    ,state_desc AS [Status]
    ,size / 128 AS [Size(MB)] --Number of 8KB pages / 128 = MB
    ,'ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE (NAME = ' + QUOTENAME(f.[name])
    + CHAR(9) /* Tab */
    + ',FILENAME = ''' + @newDriveAndFolder + CHAR(92) /* Backslash */ + f.[name]
    + CASE WHEN f.[type] = 1 /* Log */ THEN '.ldf' ELSE '.mdf' END  + ''''
    + ');'
    AS [Create new TempDB files]
FROM sys.master_files f
WHERE f.database_id = DB_ID(N'tempdb')
ORDER BY f.[type];
```

This will generate the T-SQL statements you need to run to move the files to the new `drive:\folder` you want. (click image to make larger)

[image: Image showing 2 rows with details on TempDB files and T-SQL statements to move them]

When you have ran your moving statements, you can run the above query again, to check that the `Current Location` column is now showing your new `drive:\folder`.

[image: Image showing TempDB files' new locations]

Once you're happy with your changes, **restart the SQL Server service**.